# Почему мой код не работает и как это исправить? Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему мой код не работает.
Бьёт ошибку "Cannot have more than one Element child of a Document".

```
  var a = document.createElement("form");
  a.setAttribute("action", "thisheader.php");
  var b = document.createElement("input");
  b.setAttribute("hidden", 1);
  b.setAttribute("value", "14");
  b.setAttribute("name", "art");
  var c = document.createElement("textarea");
  c.setAttribute("name", "comment");
  var d = document.createElement("input");
  d.setAttribute("name", "name");
  d.setAttribute("placeholder", "Как Вас зовут?");
  a.appendChild(b);
  a.appendChild(c);
  a.appendChild(d);
  document.appendChild(a);
```

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в последней строке вашего кода, в которой вы пытаетесь добавить элемент `a` непосредственно к объекту `document`. В DOM (Document Object Model) документ может содержать только один корневой элемент, который обычно является элементом `<html>`. Поэтому вы не можете добавить форму `(<form>)` напрямую в `document`.

Вам следует прикрепить вашу форму к существующему элементу внутри тела документа (`<body>`). Пример правильного способа добавления элемента:

```
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Или если вы хотите добавить форму в конкретный элемент, сначала найдите этот элемент по его идентификатору или любому другому селектору, а затем добавьте к нему форму. Например, если у вас есть элемент с идентификатором `container`:

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.appendChild(a);
```

когда вы создаете скрытое поле формы (`input` с атрибутом `hidden`), правильный способ установить его тип - это указать `type` в качестве атрибута, а его значение должно быть `"hidden"`.